# Непростая выборка из MySQL

Tags: mysql

hello! Есть табличка в БД для хранения сообщений. Поля: `from_id` (от кого), `to_id`(кому), `msg` (сообщение), `date, status`. Задача простая - сделать выборку из таблицы для пользователя на сайте, так, чтобы запрос возвращал статистику сообщений  - общее кол-во сообщений с определенным юзером и кол-во сообщений со статусом "1" (непрочитанные) для этого же определенного юзера. Задача-то простая, но загвоздка в том, что `id` этого нашего пользователя может находиться и в поле `from_id` и в поле `to_id`, что вводит меня в ступор.

Эту проблему я решил когда-то говнокодом : делал три (!) запроса к БД, два из которых  происходили внутри цикла. Но так дело не пойдет, поэтому хотелось бы услышать советы профессионалов.

Демо-таблица [здесь](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/901958/1)

Comment: Добавил дополнительное поле (идентификатор связи), и изменил тип 'status' для подсчёта непрочитаных. Посмотрите: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0403b/1

PS. Конечно IF в запросе не очень красиво...

Comment: @istem, community_id - заполнена только для пользователя с айди=3? А для остальных пользователей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поменял поле статус на обычный int. Пример SQL-запроса для пользователя с id = 3:

```
SELECT m.from_id as user, 
   m.to_id as another,
   count(m.from_id) as sended,
   sum(m.status) as sended_unread,
   x.c as recieved,
   x.s as recieved_unread
FROM messages AS m

LEFT JOIN (SELECT to_id, 
                  from_id,
                  count(to_id) as c,
                  sum(status) as s
             FROM messages
         GROUP BY to_id, from_id) as x

ON (x.to_id = m.from_id AND x.from_id = m.to_id)

WHERE m.from_id = 3

GROUP BY user, another
```

Все подсчеты делает БД. В результате имеем список собеседников, количество отправленных/полученных сообщений в целом + непрочитанных отправленных/полученных.

[Демо](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b219/77/0).

Comment: @Khvorostin, ничего себе запросик получился! Спасибо. К тому же вы еще немного добавили функциональности - идет подсчет отдельно и полученных и отправленных сообщений.

Answer (score 0):

Пока ждал ответа, по-моему проблему решил :

```
public function getUsers(){
    $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $result =  $this->db->query("SELECT to_id,from_id,status FROM ".DB_PREF                                             ."messages WHERE to_id='$id' OR from_id='$id'");
    $result->num_rows;
    if (!$result->num_rows) return("Ваша книга пуста ");
    $opponents = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        if ($row['to_id'] == $id) $opp = $row['from_id'];
            else $opp = $row['to_id'];
        if (!isset($opponents[$opp])) {
            $opponents[$opp]['count'] = 0;
            $opponents[$opp]['status']  = 0;
        }
        $opponents[$opp]['count'] += 1;
        if ($row['status'] == 1 && $row['to_id'] == $id) $opponents[$opp]['status'] += 1;
    }
    return json_encode($opponents);
}
```

В возвращенном массиве индекс - это id собеседника, значение элемента - кол-во сообщений, ключ status - кол-во непрочитанных сообщений

Answer (score 0):

А вот и более простой вариант запроса :)
Интересно то, что CASE используется в условии GROUP BY:

```
SELECT from_id, to_id, count(*) as total, sum(status) as unread 
FROM messages
WHERE from_id = $id or to_id = $id
GROUP BY ( CASE WHEN from_id = $id THEN to_id else from_id END )
```

Comment: @turboon, ща мы это дело проверим. Довольно лаконично у вас получилось. Скажите, в моем ответе на собственный вопрос вся обработка запроса идет с помощью php. У вас - непосредственно в sql. Что работает быстрее и менее нагружает сервер?

Comment: @turboon, у вас все работает, кроме количества непрочитанных.Выбивает совершенно непредсказуемые числа qlfiddle.com/#!2/901958/61

Comment: @turboon, да нет, все ок. Просто у меня статус был enum, я поменял на int, все заработало!