# Требуется помощь с sql-запросом

Tags: mysqli

Сам запрос, ужасно громоздкий

```
$req = $mysqli->query("SELECT cn.*, (SELECT `login` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id`=cn.`user_id`) AS `login_user_id`,
(SELECT `login` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id`=cn.`id_user`) AS `login_id_user`,
(SELECT `fio` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id`=cn.`user_id`) AS `fio_user_id`,
(SELECT `fio` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id`=cn.`id_user`) AS `fio_id_user`,
(SELECT `avatar` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id`=cn.`user_id`) AS `avatar_user_id`,
(SELECT `avatar` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id`=cn.`id_user`) AS `avatar_id_user`,
(SELECT `date_last` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id`=cn.`user_id`) AS `date_last_user_id`,
(SELECT `date_last` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id`=cn.`id_user`) AS `date_last_id_user`,
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `mail` WHERE `mail`.`id_user`=cn.`id_user` AND `mail`.`user_id`=cn.`user_id` OR `mail`.`id_user`=cn.`user_id` AND `mail`.`user_id`=cn.`id_user`) AS `count_mail`,
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `mail` WHERE `mail`.`read`='0' AND `mail`.`user_id`=cn.`id_user`) AS `new_mail` FROM `contacts` cn WHERE cn.`id_user`= '".$user['id']."' OR cn.`user_id`= '".$user['id']."' ORDER BY cn.`id` DESC LIMIT ".$start.", ".$message);
```

Требуется во вложенном цикле узнать кол-во новых сообщений. Это у нас

```
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `mail` WHERE `mail`.`read`='0' AND `mail`.`user_id`=cn.`id_user`) AS `new_mail`
```

таким образом не работает. Без вложенного запроса можно сделать так

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `mail` WHERE `user_id`= '".$user['id']."' AND `read`='0'")->num_rows;
```

но нужно сделать во вложенном.

Структура БД

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mail` (
`id` int(11) auto_increment,
`id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`text` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
`read` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
`status` int(1) default '1',
`time` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contacts` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT
CHARSET=utf8;
```

И еще вопрос: как можно сократить такой огромный sql-запрос?

Comment: создайте пример на http://sqlfiddle.com со структурой (в том числе и users) и данными. а также расскажите что означают user_id и id_user...

Comment: id_user - ид отправителя, user_id - ид получателя.

Answer (score 1):

Видим в запросе такой блок:

```
(SELECT login FROM users WHERE users.id=cn.user_id) AS login_user_id,
(SELECT login FROM users WHERE users.id=cn.id_user) AS login_id_user,
(SELECT fio FROM users WHERE users.id=cn.user_id) AS fio_user_id,
(SELECT fio FROM users WHERE users.id=cn.id_user) AS fio_id_user,
(SELECT avatar FROM users WHERE users.id=cn.user_id) AS avatar_user_id,
(SELECT avatar FROM users WHERE users.id=cn.id_user) AS avatar_id_user,
(SELECT date_last FROM users WHERE users.id=cn.user_id) AS date_last_user_id,
(SELECT date_last FROM users WHERE users.id=cn.id_user) AS date_last_id_user,
```

Структурируем его:

```
(SELECT login AS login_user_id,
        fio AS fio_user_id,
        avatar AS avatar_user_id,
        date_last AS date_last_user_id
   FROM users 
  WHERE users.id = cn.user_id) 

(SELECT login AS login_id_user,
        fio AS fio_id_user,
        avatar AS avatar_id_user,
        date_last AS date_last_id_user
FROM users 
WHERE users.id = cn.id_user)
```

Объединяем в один запрос:

```
SELECT u1.login     AS login_user_id,
       u1.fio       AS fio_user_id,
       u1.avatar    AS avatar_user_id,
       u1.date_last AS date_last_user_id,
       u2.login     AS login_id_user,
       u2.fio       AS fio_id_user,
       u2.avatar    AS avatar_id_user,
       u2.date_last AS date_last_id_user
  FROM users AS u1, 
       users AS u2
 WHERE u1.id = cn.user_id 
   AND u2.id = cn.id_user
```

Cмотрим на этот фрагмент:

```
SELECT cn.*, 
/* ... */
FROM contacts cn 
WHERE cn.id_user = '" . $user['id'] . "' 
   OR cn.user_id = '" . $user['id'] . "' 
ORDER BY cn.id DESC 
LIMIT ". $start . ", " . $message;
```

Логика лимита не понятна, поэтому я его опущу. А вот все остальное вполне трансформируется в несколько строк, которые добавятся к нашему запросу:

```
  SELECT cn.id,
         cn.id_user,
         cn.user_id,
         u1.login     AS login_user_id,
         u1.fio       AS fio_user_id,
         u1.avatar    AS avatar_user_id,
         u1.date_last AS date_last_user_id,
         u2.login     AS login_id_user,
         u2.fio       AS fio_id_user,
         u2.avatar    AS avatar_id_user,
         u2.date_last AS date_last_id_user
    FROM contacts AS cn,
         users AS u1, 
         users AS u2             
   WHERE u1.id = cn.user_id 
     AND u2.id = cn.id_user
     AND ( 
             cn.id_user = " . $user['id'] . " 
          OR cn.user_id = " . $user['id'] . " 
         )
ORDER BY cn.id DESC
```

[Как работать с сообщениями - уже было рассказано](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/217557/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-mysql). Попробуйте добавить эту часть самостоятельно.

Comment: Если сделать по вашему, то кривовато выводится.
Скрин - http://gruzimfile.ru/file/624

Comment: Правильно. Потому как собираются данные как об отправителе, так и получателе. Данные не группируются, и если пользователь А имеет переписку с пользователями Б, В и Г, то и отобразится он три раза. Если нужно просто посчитать число сообщений для пользователя, то не понятно, зачем выбирать данные о собеседниках? Либо делайте разные запросы, либо обрабатывайте полученные данные PHP.